# How to put UICollectionView and button in UIPageControl in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

This is my collectionview when i swipe it scrolls,
[image]i have putted UICollectionView and button in UIPageControl, when swipe UICollectionView scrolling, and button view not scrolling smoothly as works as normal UIPageControl
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if its your English or the hierarchy of your views, but something is not right. You put a UICollectionView and a UIButton in a UIPageControl?! Please clarify as it does not make any sense.

Comment: See edited question Jasper

Comment: You will have to show some code too. Like `scrollViewDidScroll` if you have that implemented

Comment: http://dpaste.com/1RAE9ZM see this code @Jasper

Comment: At the end of the method you call `[self pageChange];`, what does that method do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think it has something to do with your `CATransitions`

Try changing the last piece of the method so you use `UIView` animations instead of `CATransitions`:

```
if(pageControl.currentPage==pageControl.numberOfPages-1)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{

                         dayRadialCollection.alpha = 0.0f;
                         addWeek.alpha = 1.0f;
                         removeWeek.alpha = 1.0f;

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }];
}
else {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{

                         dayRadialCollection.alpha = 1.0f;
                         addWeek.alpha = 0.0f;
                         removeWeek.alpha = 0.0f;

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }];
}
```

There is also no need to hide the elements, as `alpha 0.0f` will not show them anyway.